# Can or should editors who unnecessarily edit posts be flagged or down-voted?

Tags: discussion, edits

I notice that no matter how well formed my question is someone always comes along and edits it. Most of the time I just leave it alone. But occasionally I'll revert because the editor is doing something completely unnecessary (probably to gain more points). Is their a method to flag users who are making edits without need?

Most recently this question: [Why does this query work in SQL management studio but not php through mssql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31325365/why-does-this-query-work-in-sql-management-studio-but-not-php-through-mssql)

A user (with very high reputation) edited my post by deleting two characters. I can't even tell from the diff what two characters he deleted. The edit was clearly bogus.

I have other questions like this but the point isn't throwing people under the bus. The point is how can we stop rewarding this bad behavior?

Comment: You don't get any reputation from edits once you have at least 2k reputation and can edit immediately.  And as for the edit in question, it was an attempt to change the error message from code formatting to quote formatting.  Nothing malicious but maybe not very helpful either.

Comment: What about, if I decide to edit your post, just to retract a previously placed downvote? Would you actually bother with such? Don't be such suspicious about edits made from high rep users, that actually improve your posts!

Comment: That edit was done in good faith. Marking such a long string as code makes it an unreadly long scrolling string. You *may* want to break it up in readable lines, just as it happens in your terminal.

Comment: "The edit was clearly bogus." No, it was not. It removed *inappropriate* code formatting from some text that clearly wasn't code and added the *appropriate* block quote formatting. Your suspicions about the intent of the edit being malevolent or jumping to the conclusion that it was *bad behavior* are incorrect. Code formatting (as the name indicates) should be applied to **code**.

Comment: Wow guys. Take it easy. I wasn't attacking anyone just trying to understand the system. Isn't that what this forum is for?

Comment: It's also worth noting while the user was trying to change it form a code block to a block quote it was still a code block when he was done. Isn't it understandable that I might be annoyed by the edit?

Comment: Your approach was in fact accusatory. *A very high rep user* made an *edit that was clearly bogus*, thus engaging in *bad behavior* (of which none except the user's rep was true) is a clear attack on that "very high rep user* that says *this high rep user made malevolent changes to my post to cause bad things to happen to me* (none of which is true). If you want to understand the rules, read the [help/editing] about why editing of posts is allowed, and if you have specific questions about why a user made an edit, ask that user via an @user coment. It's almost always wrong to assume bad intent.

Comment: (cont) If you don't want to contact the specific user, a better approach to asking here might have been *A user with considerably more experience than me made an edit to my post that I don't understand. Can someone help me figure out why it was done and what the improvement was?* Such an approach casts no aspersions on the editor, does not accuse them of *bad* behavior, and does not come across as poorly. Rather than make the jump to *a much more experienced user edited my post and because I don't see why it's bogus and it's bad behavior*, try a not so cynical view and thank them for helping.

Comment: "It's also worth noting while the user was trying to change it form a code block to a block quote it was still a code block when he was done." No, it wasn't. It's only a code block now because you reverted the change.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The change here was removing two spaces and adding a block quote character >.  This helped the error message read a little bit clearer, or at least in their minds it did.

I wouldn't consider an edit like this *bogus*, but it was minor.  There are a few other things that could have been improved there.

Now, they're above the threshold at which they can gain reputation for any edits, so they're doing it because they think that they can improve the question.  Moreover, the edit wasn't malicious, nor did it remove any content from the original question, so it's unlikely that they're going to be punished or charged after for "bad behavior".  In that scenario, contact the editor through @-notifications and let them know that you felt the edit was too minor and that you were rolling it back.

Comment: _"Now, they're above the threshold at which they can gain reputation for any edits, so they're doing it because they think that they can improve the question."_ That's the major point in context. The OP seems to be seriously disturbed about higher rep users, can just straight away edit their quesitons.

Comment: I did not realize high reputation users didn't get points for an edit. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 10):

You have exactly four undeleted posts with revisions by people other than you.

The one you've linked to, https://stackoverflow.com/posts/31325365/revisions, was clearly motivated by a desire to make the error message more readable by letting the whole message be visible without scrolling. It's arguable that it actually made it less readable by changing it from a monospace font to a non-monospace font, especially given that barely any scrolling was needed before anyway. It's subjective, and you have every right to revert the edit if you think it makes the post worse. Nonetheless the edit was made in good faith, by somebody with absolutely nothing to gain from making it apart from (in his opinion) improving the quality of the post. It was not "clearly bogus".

The other three all *clearly improve* the posts being edited. https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14880430/revisions fixes spelling errors. https://stackoverflow.com/posts/29087135/revisions replaces a weird spelling nobody uses with a standard one, which helps for clarity and searchability. https://stackoverflow.com/posts/12919962/revisions replaces a useless, ambiguous tag with a precise one.

Only one of these edits was made by someone of low enough rep to gain rep by editing. None of them at all were "bad behaviour". The suggested edit system certainly *does* reward bad behaviour with rep, but none of the edits people have made to your posts are examples of this.